# Soap service throws "The response ended prematurely, with at least<X> additional bytes expected." (IOException)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, soap, .net-core, gzip

i'm migrating code from asp.net to core 3.1.
I'm having the following trouble with a Soap Service:
When I call the service's method, I get an IOException with this message:
**"The response ended prematurely, with at least  additional bytes expected."**
The  number is the amount of bytes which couldn't be read from the response stream (the remaining bytes).

- The response is compressed with gzip.
- In the ASP.Net code, the Soap service method was a synced method, and the one in the Core is Async method.

Moreover, after creating the service from the .WSDL file, I needed to change the service's base URL inside the Reference.cs file from  http to https because all the responses returned with a Redirected status.
When I changed the Reference.cs file manually, I got errors, so I created a CustomBinding in order to inject the URL with the Https schema:

```
var customBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = 20000000,
        AllowCookies = false,
        BypassProxyOnLocal = false,
        ReaderQuotas = XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max,
        TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };

customBinding.CreateBindingElements().AddRange(
    new HttpsTransportBindingElement
    {
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 20000000,
        MaxBufferSize = 20000000,
    });

_service = new masterPricerPortTypeClient(customBinding, new EndpointAddress("https://..."));
_service.Endpoint.Binding = customBinding;
```

After it, I can see in a network tracer that this request was responded with a valid response, but when I'm trying to process the response, I get the IOException above.

I tried to call the action from the service client:

```
SearchReply searchReply = await _service.SearchAsync(searchRequest);
```

But I get the Exception in this line of the code above.

I tried to call the method via HttpWebRequest:

```
using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var contentStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        contentStream.ReadTimeout = 1000;
        var bufferSize = 2048;
        var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        var result = new List<byte>();

        try
        {
            var readBytes = 0;
            while ((readBytes = contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer).Result) != 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < readBytes; i++)
                {
                    result.Add(buffer[i]);
                }
            }
```

But I get the Exception inside the "while" loop after few read actions.

Did anyone had this issue or can assist please?

Comment: What are the response headers?  Is there a content-length header?

Comment: Yes, the content-length header has the amount of characters (not the bytes amount) in the soap response

Comment: If that's the case, it's a protocol violation by the server.  See: "When a Content-Length is given in a message where a message-body is allowed, its field value MUST exactly match the number of OCTETs in the message-body. HTTP/1.1 user agents MUST notify the user when an invalid length is received and detected."https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4

Comment: Thank you for that. Ok, so what should I do if I get this header in the response from the soap service?

Comment: Fix the service.  Or use a TcpClient to implement the non-standard protocol the server is using.